# Confusion Regarding Slowness Of Recursive Find

Tags: find, recursive

This command takes greater than 2 minutes to return:

```
find . -type d -wholename ./dev-abcd/efgh
```

It makes me think there's many subdirectories.  I checked that with the below command, which returned nearly instantly:

```
 ls -lR | grep "^d" | wc -l
    2002
```

When I make a slight variation of this command to search for a similar directory to `find`, the command also returns nearly instantly.

```
ls -lR | grep "^d" | grep "efgh"
```

This makes me think that there must be many hidden subdirectories.  But, I don't see many:

```
ls -ap | egrep "^\..*/$" | wc -l
       3
```

Why is `find` performing so slowly that it takes 2 minutes to return a result that `ls` + `grep` returns within seconds?

Comment: Hidden directories? `ls -lR` doesn't list hidden directories or their contents by default, IIRC.

Comment: Right - the command at the end was meant to show there aren’t many hidden directories

Comment: Many at the top level. It doesn't say anything about nested ones.

Comment: Oh good point. I can adjust the command in the morning to show a more accurate hidden subdirectory result

Comment: Most likely the other commands take advantage of the cache. If you run the `find` again, after the `ls -lR`, does it take that long? By the way, wouldn't this return the same, without having to traverse the whole tree?: `test -d ./dev-abcd/efgh && find ./dev-abcd/efgh -d`